# Composing teleportation circuit in Qiskit Circuit Composer

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience, teleportation

I'm trying to create the teleportation circuit in IBM Qiskit Circuit Composer.

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[3];
creg a[3];   // should be crz
creg b[4];   // should be crx

h q[1];
cx q[1],q[2];
barrier q; //[0];

cx q[0],q[1];
h q[0];
barrier q;

measure q[0] -> a[0];
measure q[1] -> b[0];
barrier q;
```

This gives me the following circuit till the 3rd measurement barrier. How do I add `CRX` and `CRZ` gates - to obtain the circuit as shown in the picture? Also, how to change the names of the classical registers from `a3`, `b4` to `crz` and `crx`?

[image: Teleportation Circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crx` and `crz` are classical register. The gates `CRX` or `CRZ` mean that you apply the `X` gate on qubit 2 if the measurement on the classical register `crx` is a 1, that is if qubit 1 (`q1`) is in the $|1\rangle$ state; and you will apply the `Z` gate on qubit 2 if the classical register `crz` is 1.

This can be done in qiskit with `c_if` operation. You can see example of the teleportation code in Qiskit here: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html

---

Anyway, if you want to use OPENQASM, then you can do it as follow:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[3];
creg crzz[3];   // since crz is already taken I use crzz instead
creg crxx[4];   // Again I use crxx instead of crx

h q[1];
cx q[1],q[2];
barrier q; //[0];

cx q[0],q[1];
h q[0];
barrier q;

measure q[0] -> crzz[0];
measure q[1] -> crxx[0];
barrier q;

if(crzz==1) z q[2];
if(crxx==1) x q[2];
```

Here is the image of the circuit when using Circuit_Composer option within IBMQ Experience environment.

[image]

Comment: thanks @KAJ226! Now, if I measure q2, I should get the same state as q0 right?

Comment: Yes. The idea is the state of $q0$ has teleported to $q2$. If $q0$ was in the state $|1\rangle$ then measurement on $q2$ will only have value 1.

Comment: But I also should point out that the condition operations we defined above is not executable on current hardware, as far as I know of. Therefore you can only do this on simulator. To run the teleportation on hardware, you need to make a little modification. See here:  https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html#real_qc